# Prettify compiling C++ from Command Line

Tags: c++, batch-file, cl

I'm playing with compiling C++ from native Windows CMD via VS 2017 compiler (vsvarsall.bat setup).

Is there any way to reduce the output of `cl` command, like Microsoft rigths for compiler and linker?

Also, offtop question: is it possible to compile code with UNICODE or ANSI strings (like I'm able to build from Visual Studio IDE), or am I gotta use manual `#define`s?

Comment: There's a broad variety of techniques available to filter specific programs' output.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as "too broad"? It is a very specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, see the [`/nologo` compiler flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nologo-suppress-startup-banner-c-cpp).

I'd guess the second is why people are voting to close--there's quite a variety of ways to deal with ANSI/Unicode strings, and without quite a bit more definition of what you really want, chances are pretty poor that anybody can give a meaningful answer.